# HTML Multiple Form Actions/Outcomes

Tags: html, forms, submit, action

Basically Im trying to build a page menu but in the form of a "Search users..." box. So basically when user enters the text "John Smith" the action="JohnSmith.html" but if they type "Mary Smith" the action would ="MarySmith.html".

From what I've been told so far there can only be one action per . Would what I wan't be possible using only HTML, If not how could I go about making this "Search User/Page Selector"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before you submit your form you can change the action depending upon the value of your text box in a java script function.

```
if(textboxValue=='John Smith'){
document.form.action="Action1";
}else if(textboxValue=='Mary Smith'){
document.form.action="Action1";
}
document.form.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed! Although I'm completely new to this, how do I link this into my form?

Comment: You can call a java script function onclick of your submit button. And in that java script function you can fetch the value of your text box using document.getElementById("form field name"), and then based on the value of your text field you can call different actions as shown above

Answer (score 0):

HTML marks up documents.  It's a markup language.  When browsers hit the markers, the HTML tags, they respond.  By itself, HTML will not be readily usable to process data conditionally.  Another program will be needed to process the HTML form.  For these reasons, I suggest, No, HTML will not be a good choice for this task.

PHP, ASP, JSP or maybe even javascript would be good choices for processing form data.  A stronger answer would require more structure to the question.  Thanks.